# Are men genetically programmed to seek multiple sexual partners more than women?

Tags: sexuality, evolutionary-psychology, sex-differences

I saw [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31285) on Skeptics Stack Exchange. Someone says "obviously, yes". The reasoning is that men have cheap sperm whereas females have expensive eggs. Hence, most males, in most species, will be seeking multiple sexual partners more than women.

Is this true? If so, what would be good reliable sources? Is this obvious?

I thought the idea that men seek quantity is the central term of evolutionary psychology in sexual selection.

Comment: I think that, yes, the evidence overwhelmingly supports the proposition that, on average, men have less restricted sociosexual orientation. It's not something that is established by a single study or anything, but rather an entire body of evidence which in total supports the proposition. I might give a more complete answer, but for now I recommend this [blog post by David Schmitt](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/sexual-personalities/201706/what-type-person-would-agree-have-sex-stranger).